# Validador Unique Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii

para los pocos que utilizan este framework, estoy con un problema. No hay forma de que funcione correctamente el validador unique, al utilizarlo funciona y me tira el msj de error pero también lo valida al hacer un update, cosa que no debería y no me deja actualizar. He revisado en internet lo referido a scenarios y tampoco me funciona. Cree un scenario 'create' y sigue haciendo lo mismo o directamente no valida nada. Alguien sabe como resolverlo?

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Marcas();
        $model->scenario = 'create'; // única linea que agregue aca
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $datos = [
                'accion' => 'create',
            ];
            if ($model->save()) {                                
                echo Json::encode($datos);                           
            }                                       
        } else {           
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model
            ]);
        } 
    }


public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())  && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->save()) {               
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success',[
                    'message' => Html::encode('El registro se actualizo correctamente'),
                ]);
            }else{
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error',[
                    'message' => Html::encode('El registro no se pudo actualizar'),
                ]); 
            } 
            return $this->redirect('index');
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

 public function actionValidation() {
        $model = new Temporadas;
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    }
```

y esto esta en el modelo

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['create'] = ['codigo','nombre', 'cuit'];
    return $scenarios;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [          
        [['codigo','nombre'],'required'],
        ['codigo','unique','on' => 'create'],
        [['codigo'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
        [['nombre', 'color_marca'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['cuit'], 'string', 'max' => 13],
    ];
}
```

Esta es la vista

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use demogorgorn\ajax\AjaxSubmitButton;
use yii\web\View;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Marcas */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form-group mt-3 card-grid p-3">
    <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-container']); ?>   
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        [
            'id' => $model->formName(), 
            'enableClientValidation' => true, 
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute('marcas/validation'), 
            'fieldConfig' => ['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false, 'class' => 'd-none']],
            'errorSummaryCssClass' => 'alert alert-danger',
        ]
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'codigo')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => "off", 'autofocus' => true]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'nombre')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => "off"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'cuit')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => "off"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!-- BOTON GUARDAR AJAX  -->
            <?php AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
                'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Guardar'),
                'useWithActiveForm' => $model->formName(),
                'ajaxOptions' => [
                    'type'=>'POST',
                    'url'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'create' : Url::to(['update', 'id' => $model->codigo]),
                    'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(data){
                        data = JSON.parse(data);                          
                        if(data.accion=="create"){
                            toastr.success("Se registro correctamente")                          
                        }                     
                        $.pjax.reload({container:"#pjax-container"});                       
                    }')
                ],
                'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => 'submit'],
                ]);
            AjaxSubmitButton::end(); ?> 
            <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Cancelar'), ['cancelar'], ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) ?>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>  
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Tambien he probado otras cosas que vi, pero nada funciona.
Esto lo estoy haciendo en un template avanzado no en el básico. No se que otro dato relevante puedo agregar porq la base de datos esta perfecta, a lo que yo voy es que el validador funciona correctamente, solo que quiero que no lo haga en el update, por eso cree ese scenario y no funciona. Ese es el unico codigo que agregue.

Comment: pon el código de las rules en el modelo, y el controller de como lo estás usando

Comment: la forma de solucionarlo es con scenarios, danos mas detalle de tu codigo y base de dato

Comment: podrías poner la estructura de tu bd y revisar si efectivamente ningún código está repetido en tu bd?

Comment: También el action de tu update

Comment: La estructura no tiene nada raro, el problema es del codigo, porq lo he probado con otros campos y otras tablas y en todos hace lo mismo, tambien actualize la version a la ultima. 2.0.15. Los metodos para crear y agregar funcionan bien en todo el programa, quise agregar eso para ir mejorando las cosas y parece un problema de la implementacion, es como si no me tomara el scenario, incluso he comprobado que al escenario lo crea. Cuando dejo solo el unique me valida en los dos lados pero funciona y tira el msj de error, cuando agrego el 'on' => 'create' ya no valida en ninguno de los dos.

Comment: no tienes algun listener como beforeValidate? beforeSave ? sí es así ponlo, y también tu vista, del form, se que es mucho código pero al menos en lo que llevas puesto no se ve el error, debe de estar en otro lado

Comment: te dejo un codigo operativo ,https://github.com/danitoro97/liltalk/blob/master/models/Usuarios.php

Comment: No tengo nada de eso, ahí agregue la vista y el actionValidate que tengo en el controlador. No entiendo porq no funciona. Todos los demas validadores funcionan correctamente, excepto los escenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en `actionValidation()`, ya que si te das cuenta estás validando `$model`

```
public function actionValidation() {
    $model = new Temporadas; // -----> este es el model que estás validando 
      //y que no tiene el scenario create

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model); // aquí lo validas
    }
}
```

Como habrás visto el model que validas no tiene el scenario create, por eso nunca te lo tomaba en cuenta.

puedes pasarlo como parametro el scenario de la siguiente forma

```
public function actionValidation($scenario) {
    $model = new Temporadas(['scenario' => $scenario]); // pasas el scenario
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

En tu form tendrías que cambiar esto

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
    [
        'id' => $model->formName(), 
        'enableClientValidation' => true, 
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute([
             'marcas/validation', 
             'scenario' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'create' : 'default' // aquí es el cambio
         ]), 
        'fieldConfig' => ['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false, 'class' => 'd-none']],
        'errorSummaryCssClass' => 'alert alert-danger',
    ]
); ?>
```

Comment: La verdad es que tiene mucho sentido jaja, es la primera vez con un framework y se me presentan problemas todo el tiempo. Mañana lo pruebo y comento. Te agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Tenes que poner required y unique para que funcione
[['nrodoc','cuil'],'unique'],
[['nrodoc','cuil'],'required'],

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]